# Having a Service Toast receive SMS messages

Tags: android

Does not display toast message,
I want to show me a toast message when I receive sms but it doesn't work

my Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.video60">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:name=".G"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".smsReciver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>


    </application>
</manifest>
```

my code

public class smsReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(G.context,"sms recived in reza",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}
class G

```
public class G extends Application {
    public static Context context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context=getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you given sms RECEIVE_SMS permission?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include it in the code above

Comment: try using `context` instead of `G.context`

Comment: I did but it didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

**put this on your onReceive function**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sms recived in reza",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```